# TFS: comparing changesets

Tags: version-control, tfs, changeset

In TFS we can find "compare" a file between 2 changesets. Is it possible to compare 2 changesets. Say take changeset "r" as reference and compare it with changeset "s" and find the files/folders which were added/removed/delted/edited ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have VS2008 or earlier you'll need [TFS power tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx) installed then you can compare a folder. It will show you which files are only on one side or the other (added, deleted) and which are different (edited).

Comment: It seems the TFS Power Tools are not a necessity.  I only have VS Team Explorer 2010 installed and can access the dialog box by right clicking a folder in the Source Control Explorer.

Comment: I think you need the powertools in VS 2005/8 but folder compare is included in 2010